# javascript / jquery: how do I get the inner window height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like... the height that excludes the address bar, bookmarks, etc. just the viewing space.

```
$(window).innerHeight()
```

appears to not work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) for this, as mentioned in the API:

> This method is also able to find the height of the window and document.
>
> ```
> $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
> $(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
> ```

As for why [`.innerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/) isn't working:

> This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use `.height()` instead.

Comment: lol, thats what I thought. as it turns out my math was just wrong. thanks!

Comment: It will give you unpredictable results unless you declare doctype <!DOCTYPE HTML> on top of your page. This fooled me many times!